# Unable to format my memory card/SD - error -69877 couldn't open device

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line, disk-format, sd-card

I can't seem to able to format my PNY 32 GB SD card

When I go to Disk Utility and try to erase it gives me error: Unmounting disk, Couldn't modify partition map and operation failed

I successfully unmounted disk2 (the SD card) via terminal but when trying to erase it it shows  error -69877 couldn't open device

I also tried command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=1024 count=1024` but it shows permission denied

System: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

Can you help please?

Comment: Do you have another SD card you can try?  SD cards are known for a high failure rate, so let's see if we can diagnose the issue.

Comment: No I don't.. although it looks like I will need to get a new one. But it's weird as the SD card was working until yesterday morning. It got corrupted after attempting to delete pictures manually in pc.

Comment: I’ve had this happen to me many times - once when I was in the middle of a shoot.  When you get your new SD be sure to come back and post an answer or update the question.  I’ll upvote

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but per this [Mac Forum discussion](https://www.mac-forums.com/threads/cant-erase-micro-sd-card-problem-resolved.355600/), SanDisk Micro-SD to SD Adapters has a 'Lock" slider that is easy to miss. After unlocking the card, I was able to reformat the microSD card with no problem.